# UIView Not Resizing to fill iPhone 6 Window

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, uiview, autolayout

I have a `UITableView` in my .xib file.  I have this password protected, by obscuring it with another `UIView` that has a `UITextField`.  Once the password has been entered, I remove the UIView from the superview.  However, I am running into an issue that the `UIView` is not covering up all of the `UITableView` on the 6 and 6 Plus.  How can I go about doing this, given that the UIView is not the main view in the xib, and simply added?  I use auto layout and told it to pin to leading and trailing, but it isn't working.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Why don't you use a modal view controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally managed to solve this on my own.  I already had told it to pin everything, so that rendered @NRitH answer as useless.  I simply added

```
    [password setFrame:self.navigationController.view.bounds];
```

before adding the view as a subview, and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to pin its top and bottom edges. If it's in the same view that contains the stuff that you want to obscure, then pin the edges to the edges of the obscured content. Really, though, the comment about using a modal dialog is spot on.