# UIView not resizing when added as subview to main view

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I have a UIView that I'm going to display in front of the entire view controller if the user has not yet purchased the pro version.

I need it to be a UIView and not a modal view controller because I want them to sort of see a preview to the content they will unlock.

It works great on the iPhone 6 but when testing on the 6 plus, it looks way off.

Basically having the same issue that this guy is having except his resolution does not work with me.

Similar issue:
[UIView Not Resizing to fill iPhone 6 Window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26026728/uiview-not-resizing-to-fill-iphone-6-window)

How it shouldn't look (this it how it looks on iPhone 6):
[image]

^ This is weird because when I test it on my actual iPhone 6 device, it takes up the complete space.

How it shouldn't look (this is how it looks on iPhone 6 plus):
[image]

Thank you

Comment: can you maybe show some code?

Comment: Are you using auto-layout? https://www.raywenderlich.com/115440/auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-part-1-getting-started-2

Comment: @Maysam yes, do I need to specify constraints programmatically after adding as subview?

Comment: You can do it either Stortyboard and your programatically. Just read the article I linked in my previous comment.

Comment: What are you doing to make the view fit? They don't do that automatically.

Comment: There's a soft bug in iOS that, in short, on some devices it will work if you forget a constraint, but on others it won't.  It's quite annoying. If you encounter this problem, "works on 6 but not 6plus", you're almost certainly just **forgotten a constraint**.